# How would I make destroy() method in tkinter work with my code?

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

```
from tkinter import *

class GameBoard(Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.master.title("test")
    self.grid()
    #button frame
    self.__buttonPane = Frame(self)
    self.__buttonPane.grid()
    #buttons
    self.__buttonA1 = Button(self.__buttonPane,text = "A1",command = self._close)
    self.__buttonA1.grid()

  def _close(self):
    GameBoard().destroy()


def main():
  GameBoard().mainloop()

main()
```

How would I make my function for close to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
GameBoard()
```

creates a new instance of `GameBoard`. Therefore:

```
GameBoard().destroy()
```

creates a **new** instance and calls `destroy()` on it which has no effect on the existing instance.

You want access the current instance in your `_close()` method which is done through `self`:

```
def _close(self):
    self.destroy()
```

However, this only destroys the frame (and its child windows, like the button), not the top level window (master).

To completely close the UI, you could call `self.master.destroy()` or simply `self.quit()`:

```
def _close(self):
    self.quit()
```

Answer (score 5):

self.master.destroy() will close both the parent and child process (see I.E. for example). self.destroy will close the child process. I know this is an old post, but I figured this information might still be applicable to someone.

I.E.

```
def _close(self):
    self.master.destroy()
```