# How can I use command 'destroy' in python? GUI - simple menu

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, destroy

I'm trying to build a small menu, but I have a problem, because I don't know how I can remove content of label. The text should be vanished when I click another part of menu, but it isn't work like that. I know only that I must use command 'destroy', but I don't know where and how. I ask for your help.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 

window = Tk()
Menu_bar=Menu(window)
window.geometry("400x400")

def des():
    des=Label(window,text="Marta")
    des.pack(side=LEFT)

def des2():
    des2=Label(window,text="Something")
    des2.pack(side=LEFT)


first=Menu(Menu_bar, tearoff=0)
first.add_command(label="Author",command=des)

Menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Info",menu=first)

second=Menu(Menu_bar, tearoff=0)
second.add_command(label="Click",command=des2)

Menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Info2",menu=second)


window.config(menu=Menu_bar)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could this be of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650617/how-would-i-make-destroy-method-in-tkinter-work-with-my-code

Comment: If you need to remove only content of label and not a label himself - you can create just one empty label and change label's text by menu clicks. ( e.g. `des['text'] = 'Marta'`)